# How does one query Arrow dataset's metadata? Is row partitioning allowed?

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

Arrow's Dataset feature is a great tool for a database that is ever increasing and one wants to keep adding more to it even when the data is partitioned and compressed. I have been able to successfully partition my data my columns, making filtering and querying that much faster. However does Arrow allow one to partition by row groups ?

The documentation does not explain this in detail, my aim is to partition by row and then be able to query these partitions for its metadata [ highest value, lowest value ]. Does Arrow allow this ?

So far I have experimented with fragments

```
fragments = list(dataset.get_fragments())
fragments[0].split_by_row_group()
```

however this just gives me back the files in the folder structure created by columnar partitioning.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'partition by rows'? From what you describe you may need/want a `group_by` operator to aggregate per some column(s) and then calculate min/max for such grouping. This said, to my knowledge, the aggregation/reduction operators are not yet available in Arrow.

Comment: just how we may specify partition_cols, my understanding was that we can do the same by rows. for example if i had data that spanned multiple days, it would be super helpful to partition them by date so that i can query the min and max directly from metadata, groupby is a great option too definitely but i was hoping these values can be stored while writing the files instead of derived post reading all the data in

Comment: I think that's where my misunderstanding was coming from: in your example I presume your data would have a column like `date` or something similar. This way, if you set `partition_cols` to `date` parquet would save files in `date` subfolders, each containing only the data for that specific day.  Then you should be able to read min/max for each day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parquet metadata supports storing file & row group statistics which contains the "highest value" and "lowest value" fields that you desire.  The idea of supporting something similar for IPC files has been discussed but nothing exists today.

You can query parquet metadata for individual files using [read_metadata](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_metadata.html).  The documentation around the returned metadata is not quite extensive but you can play around and find the row group statistics pretty easily.

The datasets feature does not expose these statistics to the user.  However, the datasets feature DOES make use of these statistics for you automatically.  You will sometimes see this feature referred to as "predicate pushdown" and it is (very) briefly mentioned [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#tabular-datasets).

In order to make use of the feature you will need to supply a filter (described [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#filtering-data)).  For example, assume you make the following call.

```
dataset.to_table(filter=ds.field('c') == 2).to_pandas()
```

- If there is directory partitioning on the column `c` then that will be used to filter out which files are read.
- If there are row group statistics on the column `c` (e.g. parquet) then that will be used to filter out which row groups are read.

Note: In addition to row groups there is a concept in parquet called "data pages".  There can be multiple data pages per column per row group.  These data pages may also contain statistics (depends on the writer).  Arrow does not (yet) take advantage of data page statistics when filtering (see [ARROW-13998](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13998)).

Note: In addition to the above mentioned statistics there has been work done to add bloom filters to parquet files.  Arrow does not yet have support for using these (see [ARROW-11384](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11384)).

Comment: thanks again Pace, your knowledge of parquet is super helpful !